# Suggestion or handout for (generating + roots of unity filter)

Tags: contest-math, generating-functions, roots-of-unity

Hi is there any handout suggestion for generating +roi since the topic is kind of advanced like calculus but pretty useful in the math olympiad

Answer (score 1):

The exercises in Wilf's [Generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html) are quite good -- in particular, there are exercises at the end of Chapter 2 on the roots of unity filter. For something more specifically geared towards competition math, you might try Qiaochu Yuan's [*Topics in Generating Functions*](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eqchu/TopicsInGF.pdf). Here section 6 is on the roots of unity filter, and there's a number of exercises following it.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thx you very much sir any recommendation will be accepted

Comment: Happy to help, though I'm not a "sir" ;)